# IL Callvirt equivalence?

Tags: c#, il

Is `il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, getter, null);`

the same as:

to `il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,getter);`

I'm not sure how to examine the IL that is generated on the fly, so... this is the second related question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The source for `Emit(OpCode, MethodInfo)` begins with (after validation)

```
if (opcode.Equals(OpCodes.Call) || opcode.Equals(OpCodes.Callvirt) || opcode.Equals(OpCodes.Newobj)) 
{
    EmitCall(opcode, meth, null); 
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the license implications when posting Microsoft .NET source code on StackOverflow?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but posting on StackOverflow to me counts as ["the need for developers to more deeply understand the inner workings of the source code"](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/referencesourcelicensing.aspx), but the [license itself](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframeworklicense.aspx) uses terminology specific to individuals working for a company, so I'm not sure where SO would fit for some of the wording.

Comment: did you use a decompiler, or look up the framework source?  If the former, which one?  If the latter, where's the best source?  Thanks very much for confirming my suspicion